# How to create a super user with highest access in MEAN stack app?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, express, mean-stack

I'm building a book review site with MEAN stack, where users post about books. A user can only edit and delete the posts that were created by him/her, that means my authorization is done and works perfectly.

But now what I'm trying to achieve is a super user. I'm trying to make a super user that will have access to the editing and deletion of any post regardless of who created it. I need this so that I can monitor whether anyone is posting any bad content.

For the **Authorization** purpose in the front end I'm using an interceptor class that intercepts all the `http` requests that are sent from the `service` class. The `interceptor` is given below,

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth-service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
    const authRequest = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken)
    });
    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }
}
```

It checks the token of the user who is sending the `http`request. This is checked in the backend with another middleware named `check-auth.js`. Which is given below,

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "E8PbieHoNk");
    req.userData = {email: decodedToken.email, userId: decodedToken.userId};
    next();
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(401).json({
        message: 'You are not authorized !'
      });
  }
};
```

The controller method that deletes is given here,

```
exports.deletePost = (req, res, next) => {
  Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id, creator: req.userData.userId }).then(result => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log(result);
    if(result.n > 0) {
      res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted"});
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({message: "You Unauthorized"});
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Deleting a post failed !"
    });
  });
}
```

Everything works really fine.

Now what I have tried for the purpose of making the super user to have access to deletion of any post is, I have tried to add its `userId` to the `check-auth.js` middleware and check that in controller method for `deletion` whether it is the post creator user himself or the super user, as I want both to be able to delete. But it did not work.

Here is what I tried,

```
exports.deletePost = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.userData.userId === '5c8cd83a6efff92cf85bd6eb') {
    Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id, creator: req.userData.userId }).then(result => {
      console.log(req.params.id);
      console.log(result);
      if(result.n > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted"});
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({message: "You Unauthorized"});
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Deleting a post failed !"
      });
    });
  } else {
    Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id, creator: req.userData.userId }).then(result => {
      console.log(req.params.id);
      console.log(result);
      if(result.n > 0) {
        res.status(200).json({message: "Post deleted"});
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({message: "You Unauthorized"});
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: "Deleting a post failed !"
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here the id of the user that will have highest access is `5c8cd83a6efff92cf85bd6eb`. I thought when he is logged in the delete method will get this `id` from the `jsonwebtoken` from the `check-auth` middleware and let him delete. This is what I tried.

Some clue to this problem about the better practice would mean great help. I have provided with all the details possible above.

Thank you for time and effort.